# Front End Editing with Entry From

Tags: entry, frontend-form, editing

I need to allow store managers to edit their store. I'm most of the way there and have the title field and a couple of other plain text fields set up. However there isn't any documentation available for other field types including:

- categories
- assets
- lightswitch
- relationship (entries)
- Store hours https://github.com/craftcms/store-hours/

The [documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form) is only includes examples for input and textarea fieldtypes and not any other first party custom fieldtype .
What is the best approach to being able to edit these field types?

Answer (score 2):

There is actually quite a bit of documentation on templating for various field types. Go to the [Fields section](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields) of the online docs and then select the field you are interested in, e.g. you will find a very comprehensive templating guide for assets [here](https://craftcms.com/docs/assets-fields)

Comment: I'm not sure how those links help with the first party plugin store-hours. I'm really stuck on how to get that to pull out the existing data if it exists and update with new data should the front end form be edited.